# Displaying 5 000 of pins on the map lags when map is moving

Tags: ios, swift

My UIVIewController with pins is veeery slow and lags a lot when moving map. Why?

This is how I create views:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "")
    if let annotation = annotation as? Annotation {
        view.tintColor = UIColor.bluemine
        view.pinTintColor = UIColor.bluemine
        view.canShowCallout = true
    }
    if !grouping {
        return view
    }
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        return nil
    } else {
        return view
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

within `viewDidLoad`:

```
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        mapView.register(MarkerView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
        mapView.register(ClusterMarkerView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
    }
```

`MarkerView`:

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
class MarkerView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
    internal override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        willSet {
            newValue.flatMap(configure(with:))
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
private extension MarkerView {
    func configure(with annotation: MKAnnotation) {
        let isMe = (annotation as? Annotation)?.user?.isMe ?? false
        markerTintColor = isMe ? .red : Options.shared.currentMode.hoursColor
        clusteringIdentifier = String(describing: MarkerView.self)
    }
}
```

`ClusterMarkerView`:

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
class ClusterMarkerView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {

    internal override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        willSet {
            newValue.flatMap(configure(with:))
        }
    }

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        displayPriority = .defaultHigh
        collisionMode = .circle
        markerTintColor = .blue
        centerOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -10.0)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have an empty reuse identifier? You could optimise the code slightly by putting the check for iOS 11 & grouping at the start of `viewFor annotation` and return `nil` before you allocate a view. Do you implement `mapView(_:clusterAnnotationForMemberAnnotations:)`?

Comment: by the way ...i would suggest to use a library which shows "summarize" Pins, because the overview will be better and the performance will boost ... ;) My opinion is that the user has no real support in showing that massive annotations...

Comment: What library do you suggest?;) I will check it later;) Thank you...